# Binding Dropdown list in MVC4+ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model._categoryid, new SelectList(ViewBag.abc, "_categoryid", "_categoryname"), "Select a Category")
```

This above code is working fine for binding dropdown list but i need to understand it.....can anyone elobrate it?

actually I am confused about

```
model=>model._categoryid
```

why this is required? the above line

Comment: It is specifying the selection from the dropdown will populate the `_categoryid`

Comment: Scottgu (the father of asp.net MVC) has a good writeup on this.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers

Answer (score 0):

Its an expression that evaluates to the property you want to bind to, in your case `_categoryid`. For a html helper it used to generate html attributes used when posting back, in your case `<select name="_catagoryid" ... value="TheValueOfCategoryid">`